# I have a problem about webrtc that I can't solve

Tags: webrtc

I set up the webrtc server on Linux.I want to be able to make video calls on the LAN.However, when I visit the browser, the local screen is visible and the other screen is invisible.Display "**TypeError: Either sdpMid or sdpMLineIndex must be specified**" and "**ICE failed, your TURN server appears to be broken, see about:webrtc for more details**" on the console of foxfire browser.So, I want you to help me.

Comment: In addition.I use centos7 for Linux.

Comment: If this is a JavaScript question please can you share your JavaScript code snippet.

Comment: Javascript link address:https://github.com/ddssingsong/webrtc_server.git

Comment: have you written any of your own JavaScript? If not then this is not really a JavaScript question and should not be tagged as such.

Comment: Yeah.This is someone else's room server

Comment: Thanks @Letme. I have removed the JavaScript tag.